# Double & Float method parameters execution when called in C#

Tags: c#, parameters, floating-point, double

Here's a small snippet of code, when called it outputs 'double'. Why? What's the reasoning behind this. Why doesn't it print 'float'?

```
class source
{

    static void Main()
    {
        Receiver r = new Receiver();


        r.Method1(1.1);
    }

}

class Receiver
{
    public virtual void Method1(double f) { Debug.Print("double"); }
    public virtual void Method1(float f) { Debug.Print("float"); }
}
```

TIA

Comment: got it, thanks guys for the enlightenment

Comment: this might also have to do with narrow & widening conversions and to be safe defaults to double

Comment: The reason why "double" is the default is because (1) double is far, far more precise, and (2) double is almost never slower than float, and is sometimes faster. Why is it faster? Because the chip that does floating point arithmetic almost always does all internal operations in doubles; operations on floats need to convert the floats to doubles, do the operation in doubles, and then change it back to floats when its done. Unless you are going to be allocating millions of these guys, you are almost certainly NOT memory constrained by the doubles, so use them instead of floats.

Comment: awesome, thanks eric for the insight.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To specify float call like this:

```
r.Method1(1.1f);
```

Otherwise it'll default to double, like you observed.

Here's a porition of the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9(VS.80).aspx) on double that explains why:

> By default, a real numeric literal on
>   the right-hand side of the assignment
>   operator is treated as double.

Comment: @SoftwareGeek: The `float` literal 1.1f actually represents the quantity `9,227,469 * 2^(-23)`, since all `float` numbers must be represented as a power of two times a value in the range (0..2^24).  The `double` literal 1.1 represents a fraction whose value is closer to the mathematical value of 11/10.  Note that assigning double values to floats is a perfectly reasonable thing to do which shouldn't require a typecast (but does).  Assigning floats to doubles is dodgy and should require a typecast (but doesn't).

Answer (score 5):

double is the default type for non integers. So 1.1 is a double, 1.1m is a decimal and 1.1F is a float.